# jQuery .is( selector ) - where ALL selectors match the argument?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors

`if ($('.A, .B, .C').is(':visible'))`

-**returns true if at least one of these elements matches** the given argument.

**How do I change it so that it returns true ONLY if ALL of these elements matches** the given argument?
(The argument could be changed to :hidden for this example but that is not what I am looking for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One handy way is `Array.prototype.every`:

```
if ($('.A, .B, .C').get().every(function(e) { return $(e).is(":visible"); })) {
```

...which looks less unwieldy using ES2015 (aka "ES6") arrow function syntax:

```
if ($('.A, .B, .C').get().every(e => $(e).is(":visible"))) {
```

`every` returns `true` if the callback returns a truthy value for all of the elements, `false` if the callback returns a falsy value, and stops as soon as it sees it's going to be `false`.

Another handy way is `filter`:

```
var elements = $('.A, .B, .C');
if (elements.filter(":visible").length === elements.length) {
    // Yes, they're all visible
}
```

---

You could give yourself a handy `areAll` function:

```
$.fn.areAll = function(arg) {
    return this.get().every(function(e) { // Or of course use
        return $(e).is(arg);              // the `filter` version
    });                                   // here if you prefer
};
```

...and then

```
if ($('.A, .B, .C').areAll(":visible")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: My first thought was the `.filter` also given the question context +

Comment: Clear, fast answer! The filter option looks like the better solution for me but I can see how the first option may be quicker if there is lots of data to compare. Thanks TJ

Comment: @Sach: Yeah, hard to say, the first one involves creating a bunch of temporary jQuery objects (that `$(e)`). So swings and roundabouts. :-) Glad that helped.

Comment: Great update.. thorough and useful tip . Many will appreciate @ TJ